# WordPress MultiSite URL Redirect

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, url, redirect

I have installed a WP multisite on several directories:

- site.com/name1
- site.com/name2
- site.com/name3

Each of them has its own domain name. So the domain(mygoods.com) points to site.com/name1
But internally i need those changes too.

For example when i post a link to Facebook the content get posted by site.com/name1 link instead of the "real" domain link.

I tried to set home_url and site_url in general setting in wordpress(tried also to set these changes in the db option table) but both ended up in a non working site.

Im glad for every hint. Thanks in advance